# Output converter for converting DECIMAL('100.000') in pyodbc

Tags: pyodbc, numeric

I have numeric column in one of the SQL Server tables. When I tried retrieving the data from this table, the numeric value of 100.00 has been taken in Python as DECIMAL (100.000) which is preventing me in passing this value as parameter to one of the stored procedures.

This is the bytecode I am getting for 100.000: b'\x13\x05\x01\x00\xe8vH\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

When I find length of this bytecode it is 19.

```
def decimal_converter(raw_bytes):
    struct.unpack(?, raw_bytes)
     return

cn.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_DECIMAL, decimal_converter)
```

Any help in unpacking this bytecode would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of a stored procedure that fails if you pass it a `Decimal('100.000')` value. [This code](https://pastebin.com/PeWy701U) works fine for me. You probably *don't* want to use an output converter to fix this issue, you just need to convert the `Decimal(…)` value before passing it.

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson for quick response. Casting numeric column in SQL itself works. But I'm writing a generalized code and this code needs to handle bunch of tables with columns of different datatypes. 
For example: I have a procedure named GetData and the result after its call is like

```(1, 'SQ', 'Tfm', 31, True, None, True, False, Decimal('1000000.00000'), datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 17, 18, 2, 29, 150000), 4, 1000193126)```

How can I convert just decimal datatype OR datetime datatype?

Comment: Convert those values to some other type? String, perhaps? For what purpose?

Comment: Hi @GordThompson, I also have big struggle to figure out struct.unpack format for decimal. Maybe you know the format? I'm loading data from database, and passing it to [JSONSerializer](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#jsonserializer). No problems with int, float, bool, etc, but serializer can't understand any of these datetime.*, [decimal.Decimal](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Data-Types#sql-values-received-from-the-database). I was able to figure-out unpack formats for datetime.*, but can't manage decimal.Decimal.